# How to display error message on the mern app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I'm trying to display an error message when a user tries to sign in with an unregistered user but I'm not able to get that error message on the frontend(reactjs) that I am sending from my backend(nodejs, express, MongoDB).

I am using redux to handle the state of the react app.

user login form onSubmit code:

```
   const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (isLogin) {
      dispatch(signin(data, history));
    } else {
      dispatch(signup(data, history));
    }
  };
```

actions creators for auth

```
import * as api from "../api";

export const signin = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // login the user
    const { data } = await api.signIn(formData);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data });
    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({ type: "ERROR", data: error.response.data.message });
  }
};

export const signup = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // sign up the user
    const { data } = await api.signUp(formData);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data });
    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

reducers for auth:

```
const authReducer = (state = { authData: null }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AUTH":
      localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify({ ...action?.data }));
      return { state, authData: action?.data };
    case "LOGOUT":
      localStorage.clear();
      return { state, authData: null };
    case "ERROR":
      return { state, authData: action?.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

Backend sign in code

```
const signin = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!existingUser)
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User doesn't exist." });

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      password,
      existingUser.password
    );
    if (!isPasswordCorrect)
      res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid Credentials" });

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { email: existingUser.email, id: existingUser._id },
      "test",
      { expiresIn: "1h" }
    );
    res.status(200).json({ result: existingUser, token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

sign API

```
import axios from "axios";

const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
});

export const signIn = (formData) => API.post("/user/signin", formData);
export const signUp = (formData) => API.post("/user/signup", formData);
```

Anyone, please help me with this.

Screenshots of the error response in Postman:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Rishi, have you checked your backend APIs with tools like postman ? is the backend sending error messages ? If yes, then can you please mention what do you get in response of wrong user credentials on your frontend ?

Comment: Hey Sahil, Yes I am getting error messages. I just added two screenshots. Please take a look

Comment: Hey Rishi can you please show the 'api.signIn(formData)' method ?

Comment: Hello Sahil, just added to the question

Comment: repo link: https://github.com/rishipurwar1/invoice-app

Comment: Hey rishi, I cloned you app and api repo from github. I am able to get that error message at frontend. Can you show the logs in google chrome?

Comment: Pleasr try console.log(error.response.data.message) to see error message in browser logs.

Comment: I did console.log in the sign in action creator right after the .catch(error) and I'm getting that error message. Now how to show that on the frontend

Comment: Have you implemented store in frontend ?

Comment: yes I have implemented store on the frontend

Comment: Where is store.js file in your repo ?

Comment: I didn't create a separate store.js file. That code is inside index.js at the root of the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just debugged the issue. First install redux-devtools-extension by `npm install --save redux-devtools-extension`
Then apply this in store(index.js file in your case) as follows

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import App from "./App";
import { reducers } from "./reducers";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And now you can use the error message anywhere as follows (your Auth.js file)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Input from "../utils/Input";
import Label from "../utils/Label";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import { signin, signup } from "../../actions/auth";

const Auth = () => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const formMethods = useForm();
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { authData } = auth;
  const { handleSubmit } = formMethods;

  console.log(authData);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const changeScreen = () => {
    setIsLogin(false);
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (isLogin) {
      dispatch(signin(data, history));
    } else {
      dispatch(signup(data, history));
    }
  };

  const googleSuccess = async (res) => {
    const result = res?.profileObj;
    const token = res?.tokenId;

    try {
      dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data: { result, token } });
      history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const googleFailure = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log("Google sign in was unsuccessful");
  };

  return (
    <section className="col-start-1 col-end-2 md:col-start-2 md:col-end-3 row-start-2 row-end-3 md:row-start-1 md:row-end-2 mx-3 sm:mx-0 md:my-auto">
      <div className=" w-full max-w-md bg-primaryOne px-6 py-8 rounded-md shadow-md mx-auto">
        <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
          <form className="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div className="w-full flex justify-around mb-2">
              <button
                className={`${
                  isLogin
                    ? "bg-secondaryTwo"
                    : "transition bg-transparent hover:bg-secondaryTwo"
                } text-white text-xs font-bold px-6 py-4 rounded-full`}
                type="button"
                onClick={() => setIsLogin(true)}
              >
                LOG IN
              </button>
              <button
                className={`${
                  !isLogin
                    ? "bg-secondaryTwo"
                    : "transition bg-transparent hover:bg-secondaryTwo"
                } text-white text-xs font-bold px-6 py-4 rounded-full`}
                type="button"
                onClick={() => changeScreen()}
              >
                SIGN UP
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              {!isLogin && (
                <div>
                  <Label labelName="Name" />
                  <Input inputName="name" type="text" bgColor="primaryTwo" />
                </div>
              )}
              <div>
                <Label labelName="Email" />
                <Input inputName="email" type="email" bgColor="primaryTwo" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Label labelName="Password" />
                <Input
                  inputName="password"
                  type="password"
                  bgColor="primaryTwo"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="text-center">
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => setIsLogin(!isLogin)}
                className="text-neutral font-extralight text-xs pt-6"
              >
                {authData && <h1 style={{ color: "red" }}>{authData}</h1>}
                {!isLogin
                  ? "Already have an account? Log In"
                  : "Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </button>
            </div>

            <button className="bg-secondaryTwo hover:bg-secondaryOne transition px-4 py-3 w-full rounded-md text-white font-bold mt-4 shadow-md">
              {isLogin ? "Log In" : "Sign Up"}
            </button>
            <div className="flex items-center py-6">
              <div className="w-1/2 h-px bg-white bg-opacity-40"></div>
              <p className="text-white px-1 text-xs">OR</p>
              <div className="w-1/2 h-px bg-white bg-opacity-40"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <GoogleLogin
                clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
                onSuccess={googleSuccess}
                onFailure={googleFailure}
                cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
                render={(renderProps) => (
                  <button
                    className="bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-500 transition px-4 py-3 w-full rounded-md text-white font-bold mb-4 shadow-md"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                    disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                  >
                    <i className="fab fa-google mr-2"></i>Continue with Google
                  </button>
                )}
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </FormProvider>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

And one last thing. Check nested object before using its properties like error.response.data.message (your auth.js actions file)

```js
import * as api from "../api";

export const signin = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // login the user
    const { data } = await api.signIn(formData);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data });
    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("An error occured while ");
    const errMsg =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    dispatch({ type: "ERROR", data: errMsg });
    console.log(errMsg);
  }
};

export const signup = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // sign up the user
    const { data } = await api.signUp(formData);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data });
    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I didn't create a separate store.js file. That code is inside index.js at the root of the folder

Comment: and I am using this code now to get an error message:  
const authData = useSelector((state) => state.auth.authData); on the AuthForm.js file Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: @RishiPurwar I just make the error notification at screen now use can change its css or positioning as per your need

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now it works as expected.

But right now! when we display an error message on the login form and then the user clicks on the signup button, it still shows that login error message on the signup form. ideally, it should not show that error message on the signup form. Any idea how to fix that? One thing that came to my mind is to create a separate useState hook for sign up and log in. but I think that's not a good approach.

Comment: Yes I just added that to show the message for now. We can customize it with number of ways. You should update the redux state, error message will vanish automatically. In your case when someone click the signup option or try to login again you can update the global state by dispatching action. And yes useState() will not work as it is component level state.

Comment: what should I dispatch when someone clicks on signup?

Comment: you need to make an action and reducer to make the the auth data null again and dispatch the same. To understand you use can also disptach logout like this `dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });`  when ever you want that notification to vanish, but you must make a seprate action for vanish as well

Comment: I just edited the code again showing the same. Please check it once

Comment: thanks again for you help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, everything is working fine, and actually, there is no error happening on the frontend side. You have to check the status code of "await api.signIn(formData);" response. If it is 200, it means that everything is ok otherwise you have to check the message in the response to get the message error. As on the frontend there is thrown error to be catched.

Answer (score 0):

you can aslo use react-toastify . you can get status code and response message from error and store it in state object in reducers/auth.js and access it using useSelector() then create if else conditions according to status code and pass message to toast(#error_message#).

just see [react-toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify) and know how to use it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).